# Ruby BigDecimal and MySQL decimal precision mismatch

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, decimal, precision, bigdecimal

I'm storing some latitudes and longitudes in a MySQL database using Rails 3.0.3. Here is a part of the migration I used to create the table (note the decimal value with a given precision):

```
create_table :dummies do |t|
  t.decimal :something, :precision => 13, :scale => 10
end
```

The following RSpec example should illustrate where it's going wrong.

I use a BigDecimal for some calculations and the resulting `my_value` is a number with a large precision (larger than the one specified in the migration). I store the object in the database and retrieve it again.

Comparing the original value with the database value fails as their precision is not the same so it is no longer the same number:

```
it 'should be equals before and after save' do
  my_value = BigDecimal('4.123456789') * 5000 # more precise than defined in the migration
  dummy = Dummy.new(:something => my_value)
  location.save!
  Dummy.first.something.should == dummy.something
end
```

I understand why this is happening (the precision of the decimal in MySQL != the BigDecimal one) but can anyone tell me how I can limit the precision of the `my_value` BigDecimal before I write it to the database to make sure it respects the database constraints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In mySQL, use FLOAT for storing these geo-coordinates.  It simply makes no sense to store them as high-precision decimal.   Keep in mind that 1/60th of a degree of latitude is a nautical mile, so a foot (~ 1/3 of a meter) is around 3 microdegrees.  (3e-06)

The epsilon for IEEE single precision floating point (the error) is about 6e-08

GPS and geocoding aren't that detailed, even when you're at 179.9996 degrees.

If you're making highly detailed 200-scale topo maps or something like that, you probably already know you have to use a high-precision projection like universal transverse Mercator or Lambert or some such, because you're beyond the limit of approximating the earth as a sphere.  But, if you're doing a store-finder type of app, you don't need, don't want, and can't get, that kind of precision.

If you MUST use decimal in your Ruby program, convert to float before storing to mySQL.

Here's Randall Munroe's explanation of geocoordinate precision.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Olli. The problem is I'm using the coordinate for calculations later on so that's why I went with BigDecimal, think Floats could return strange values here, don't they? I will try your last solution, converting to floats before the validations.

Comment: @Cimm -- floats will work fine for these computations. Seriously.

Comment: Thanks again! I went for `t.float :latitude, :limit => 51` this uses a Float in Rails and stores the value as a Double in MySQL.

Comment: I didn't understand all that. But it looks like you know what you're talking about. I'll take your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like

```
new_value = number_with_precision(your_value.to_f, :precision => 13)
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, it seems converting to float before saving to the database is the way to go. The 'number_with_precision' method is a view helper, this can't be used in the model so I don't think that will help.